# [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined, using Laravel 8

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a new project but I'm getting this error and I don't know why. I'm using Laravel 8, Vue and Inertia.js.

I'm not sure if these files are important but I'll add anyways

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue({ version: 2 })
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
                '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
            },
        },
    })
    .babelConfig({
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
    })
    .version();
```

app.js

```
import InertiaApp from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(InertiaApp);

const app = document.getElementById('app');

app.setAttribute(':class',"{'loaded': loaded}");
new Vue({
    render: h => h(InertiaApp, {
        props: {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: name => import(`@/Pages/${name}`).then(module => module.default),
        },
        data(){
            return{
                loaded:true
            }
        }
    }),
}).$mount(app);
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

@inertia

</body>
</html>
```

Finally the page I'm trying to show Login.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('mounted');
    }
}
</script>
```

I don't know why this is happening or how to fix it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `const app = document.getElementById('app');` You seem to be missing a `<div id="app"> ... </div>` (... should be `@inertia` I think, never worked with it)

Comment: @brombeer I've never had to do that before, I'm going from Laravel 6 to 8. I did add an `id=app` but them got a lot of other errors

Comment: Ok, sorry, my fault then, always had to add this when working with Laravel/Vue. Will remove my comments. Good luck ;)

Comment: @brombeer don't remove it, it might help someone else

Comment: This warning is related with using `import` instead of `require`, which is resolved asynchronously. Seems to be load empty before is resolved the component, but is resolved when you "see", so no error. You can remove this warning by using `require`, but you will loose the webpack code-splitting: `require(`@/Pages/${name}.vue`).default`